# Input of integers' array of unknown size

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

I'm trying to create an array of integers of an unknown size. 
Every time I input a positive element I use realloc to increase the size of the array and store that element 
The thing is that when I run this code, I get a run-time error after 2 iterations of the while of the function create1DArray, so it's probably due to a realloc failure. 
Can anybody tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void create1DArray(int** perArray, int* size);


int main()
{
    int *perArray, size=0, i;
    create1DArray(&perArray, &size );


    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%d ",perArray[i]);
    free(perArray);
    return 0;
}


void create1DArray(int** perArray, int* size)
{
    int flag=0, i=0, x;
    *perArray=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) );
    if(*perArray==NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(!flag)
    {
        if( scanf("%d", &x)<1 || (x<0) )
        {
            printf("Invalid input!");
            free(perArray);
            exit(1);
        }

        if(!x)
        {
            if( !(*size) )
            {
                printf("The first element of the array must not be 0");
                free(perArray);
                exit(1);
            }
            flag++;
        }

        else
        {

            *perArray=(int*)realloc(*perArray, (++(*size))*sizeof(int) );
            if(*perArray==NULL)
            {
                printf("Reallocation failed!");
                free(perArray);
                exit(1);
            }
            *perArray[i++]=x;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I see two problems (and M Oehm spotted one more):

1) Your handling of size is wrong (or at least strange). Normally you'll do something like:

```
*perArray=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) );
*size = 1;
```

Perhaps even better - you should drop the `malloc` and just initialize the pointer in `main` to NULL. `realloc` works like `malloc` when called with NULL.

This would also allow you to call the function several times - something you current code doesn't allow.

2) There is a problem with your `realloc`

```
        *perArray=(int*)realloc(perArray, (++(*size))*sizeof(int) );
                                ^^^^
                      Should be *perArray
```

3) You need to dereference the pointer before indexing (noticed by M Oehm - thanks).

```
*perArray[i++]=x; ---> (*perArray)[i++]=x;
```

Comment: I changed perArray to *perArray, deleted malloc and intialized *perArray to be NULL in main. It still crashes when it runs.

Comment: There's a third error: `*perArray[i++] = x;` should be `(*perArray)[i++] = x;`.

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what you want, but take a look at how it can be done concisely (although doing realloc at each iteration is inefficient). It should be compiled with the flag *std=c11*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int input = 0;
    int * perArray = NULL;

    while(scanf("%d", &input) && input > 0)
    {
        ++size;
        perArray = (int *) realloc(perArray, sizeof(int) * (long unsigned) size);
        assert(perArray);
        perArray[size - 1] = input;
    }

    if(perArray) 
    {   
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) printf("%d ", perArray[i]);
        printf("\n");
        free(perArray);
    }

    return 0;
}
```